# How to display list data in 'Related Content' field in Tasks

Tags: 2010, workflow, task-list

I've got a holiday approval system on our Sharepoint 2010 Foundation intranet. The process is that the staff member requests a holiday by adding to a List called 'Holiday Requests', the workflow then starts and creates a task for the relevant manager to approve.

The Task that the manager is sent, however, has a field called 'Related Content' which simply says 'No Title' and is a hyperlink back to the original request details, there are none of the details of the requested dates, or even who's requested it.

I want to show in here - even if means creating additional columns rather than populating the **'Related Content'** column with something useful - the name, leave start date and leave end date, so that the approving manager has a clue what it is they're approving!

Thanks in advance for any help
James.

Answer (score 2):

James,

From SharePoint Designer you can customize the approval page.. I am sure you must have got the ID of the "Holiday Request" item in Query String...

SharePoint Designer -> Navigate to approval page -> Edit in Advanced Mode -> Drop a Display Form -> From Ribbon select Parameters, choose Query String, name the parameter correctly -> From Ribbon select Filter, choose column ID and value as Parameter -> From Ribbon Limit the item to 1..

This will let you edit the columns as well you want to show in the display form! Choose created by, details and date columns!

I don't have SharePoint Designer right now or I would have added screenshots as well...

Comment: Many thanks for your reply Arsalan. 
I have to confess though, I'm not following where to complete some of the solution you've posted. If when you're next with SharePoint Designer you could grab some screen shots, that'd be really helpful.

Thanks again
James.

Comment: I too couldn't follow what he was saying. Did you ever figure this out James?

Comment: Hey Barney, I didn't mate I'm afraid. Still an outstanding query, and still annoys the hell out of me! Any help gratefully received!